# What major steps could I have missed in creating a MapView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a MapView and I have done all requirements, added API key in main.xml, `INTERNET PERMISSION` and also add  in manifest.xml.

And still my app is showing grid lines. What else could I be missing?

Comment: A code sample would help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention that you created a `MapActivity` or that you instantiated a new instance of `MapView`. You also did not mention if you added:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

To your android manifest. Make sure you follow all the steps from: [The Hello, MapView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

Comment: yes I have add libraray and also extends activity to MapActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the API key you are using is the **debug** api key.  Using a production api key while debugging will result in only showing grid lines.

Comment: thanks but How I come to its debugging or not? i used this link to generate the key http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-mapview-generate-api-key-using-java-keytool/